# flutter_pos_printer_platform: Columns content are pushed to the right if some left columns have Thai character

Tags: flutter, posprinter

Library link: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pos_printer_platform

Hi everyone. I'm trying to print the report that have Thai character, so i used the textEncoded() method like this to render table rows:

```
        bytes += generator.row([
          PosColumn(width: 1, text: stock.id),
          PosColumn(width: 2, textEncoded: await getThaiEncoded(stock.name)),
          PosColumn(
            width: 9,
            text: getTabs(5) +
                ' ' +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.wh, 6) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.perPack, 5) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.openBal, 6) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.sale, 6) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.goodsReturn, 8) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.transfIn, 7) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.transfOut, 7) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.focX, 5) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.focY, 5) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.closeBal, 6) +
                getRightAlignedText(stock.onhand, 6),
          ),
        ]);
```

And here is the getThaiEncoded() method:

```
Future<Uint8List> getThaiEncoded(String text) async =>
    await CharsetConverter.encode(
      'Windows-874',
      text,
    );
```

And this is the result:
Print Result : -

[image]

All the rows that have 2nd column contains only Latin character (like the one i've highlighted) is perfectly aligned, but the others which have Thai, right columns take some extra spaces and pushed back to the right even though they're from the same source code. What's going on with the textEncoded() method?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you guys so much

I'm pretty sure the problem came from encoding special character process, because when i try with normal Latin character for all the reports, everything works perfectly

Comment: this is the issue link on github of the library: https://github.com/arthas1888/flutter_pos_printer_platform/issues/48